# I added custom Languge to the list of my languages

Tags: python, django

I am having problem with adding my custom languages in Django. Here is the configuration of the settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = [
('en', 'English'),
('ru', 'Russian'),
('uz', 'Uzbek'),
]

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
'uz': {
    'bidi': False,
    'code': 'uz',
    'name': 'Uzbek',
    'name_local': "O'zbek",
},
}

import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO.items() +   EXTRA_LANG_INFO.items())
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
global_settings.LANGUAGES = global_settings.LANGUAGES + [("uz", 'Uzbek')]
```

but I am having the following errror:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
```

I am using django version 2.1 and pycharm as an IDE on ubuntu 18.04. Actually according to the instructions it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: That method (summing two `.items()`) doesn't work on Python 3. See the duplicate for alternatives. Probably the easiest one is to use update: `LANG_INFO.update(EXTRA_LANG_INFO)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do not have to first convert the `LANG_INFO` dictionary into a key-value pair list and then add them together. What you can do is simply to create a new dictionary with old and new key-value pair dictionaries. I would also recommend decorating **`name`** in `LANGUAGES` for future translations. I am writing your code in the modified version below:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_noop

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', gettext_noop('English')),
    ('ru', gettext_noop('Russian')),
    ('uz', gettext_noop('Uzbek')),
]

EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'uz': {
        'bidi': False,  # right-to-left
        'code': 'uz',
        'name': 'Uzbek',
        'name_local': "O'zbek",
    },
}

# Add custom languages not provided by Django
import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **EXTRA_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO
```

And one more thing you do not have to override `LANGUAGES` attribute in **Django** `global_settings` , because you have already override it in your project settings. So this line *can be ignored*:

```py
global_settings.LANGUAGES = global_settings.LANGUAGES + [("uz", 'Uzbek')]
```